# Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 post to wall

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Is there a way to post to user's wall using the new Facebook iOS SDK through feed dialog (like it used to be possible in the old FBconnect)?

`requestForPostStatusUpdate:` requires permission for publishing to stream, which I don't want to ask users for.

Comment: @AlexanderNorway From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ :  _The Feed Dialog prompts the user to publish an individual story to a profile's feed. This does not require any extended permissions._

Comment: @Sierna My bad! Always read the note at the end..: "You do not need to request the publish_stream permission in order to use the Feed Dialog, the Requests Dialog or the Send Dialog."

Comment: I am actually looking for this answer as well. Have you been able to figure anything out since your initial post?

Comment: hey even i am looking for same..and i am lost..don't know how to use..if got something.. can you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook suggests using the older header files for posting an update. From facebook "To invoke Facebook dialogs, reference the Facebook deprecated headers. The headers can be found here ~Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/DeprecatedHeaders. Drag the whole DeprecatedHeaders folder and deselect the ''Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)'' option to add the headers as a reference."

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/ for details... seems silly that you have to implement the depreciated stuff, and then access it in a new way to make the dialogs work... but that's facebook...

Comment: can one use the depricated headers together with the current facebook SDK 3? When I drag them over to my project I get a bunch of errors.

Comment: @Sparq: you should just import Facebook.h, and not <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>, the former imports the later.

Comment: Unfortunately I just get a load of "Duplicate interface definition" errors when I do this. Even if I remove the duplicates from the DeprecatedHeaders.

Answer (score 6):

Do a global search for FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h make sure you are not importing it anywhere.  Tripped me up.